# Is there a contact book that allows partial access for apps?

Tags: contacts, privacy

In my phone book, I have both personal contacts and work-related contacts, like clients, contractors, etc.

Applications such as 'WhatsApp' are great and easy, but I do not necessarily want to add all contacts to all apps that use the contact book.

Is there **either an alternative contact** book that allows only certain people (groups?) to be shared with an app while keeping others out, **or a privacy setting** in the default contact book that allows certain contacts not to be seen by every app?

Comment: Do you have root access on your device? What Android version is it running?

Comment: Yes I have root access. At the moment Stock, 4.2.2. I'm willing to upgrade/change to another stock (i.e. Cyanogenmod) if that makes things easier.

Comment: Even with a rooted phone with Xposed installer running XPrivacy, you still can only limit the access to a yes or a no. Unfortunately, you cannot specify the exact label that the app can read from. (I just tried it with xprivacy)

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Other alternatives include LBE or, at least with Android 4.3, maybe AppOps. But all with the same effect: either the app in question can access the contacts, or not. No way to let it have access to "selected contacts", at least I've never heard of such a solution.

Comment: @Zlatty , thanks for trying this out. Maybe install a separate Contact app, and run default contacts and "private contacts" in those two. Whatsapp etc will only check one, not reading the other one. On the other hand, this would be an awesome development idea for a new contacts app!

Comment: @wolfgang - give it a try and post back!

Comment: Wolfgang, is information provided by @piquer useful? Could you please check? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The pro version of XPrivacy can do just that. I use it to allow WhatsApp selective access to contact book entries only if I know that the person in question is already registered with WhatsApp.

Blocking contacts by default:

[image]

Allowing partial access:

[image]

Comment: You have to enable/disable contacts one by one in Xprivacy. It would be nice to disable groups.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have paid version of XPrivacy right now to check the desired functionality. I see that thread is almost 2 years old. @Wolfgang Haak, could you please check this and verify? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the app in Dual Messenger mode (dual account/secure mode) and turn on the option "Use separate contacts list".

[image]

Comment: Just a note that Dual Messenger is a Samsung's specific feature. Other manufacturers may have a different name (e.g. Xiaomi's "Dual Apps") and different settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found [OpenContacts](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/opencontacts.open.com.opencontacts/) that allows you to manage a second contact book that will be isolated, so no contacts will be uploaded.

Yes, there is no way to setup partial access, however you can open chats from OpenContacts, directly. It's a good solution if you have business contacts that you use only for calling, SMS and email.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 the only vendor-agnostic solution I could find, was to use work profiles. Apps like [Shelter](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.typeblog.shelter/) help with setting this up.